# How to deal with inconsistent state during event bubbling in ReactJS component?

Tags: reactjs

I am building a simple chat client where you can open new conversations in a new tab. For now I am using single App component, supported by react-bootstrap without Redux utilizing React's state.

[image]

You can close them as well and that's the point.

I use controlled tabs from react-bootstrap, so **I have one onSelect handler on my tab**(which is triggered on Click, obviously). Inside said tab (NavItem to be accurate) **I have a button with onClick handler**.

Both handlers modifies App component's state. As far as I know in case of event React waits till it ends bubbling and then renders component. **In between this process there is inconsistency in state in both handlers. Second handler overrides state that first handler has set.**

This is my App components code:

```js
import React, {Component, PropTypes} from 'react'
import {
  Button,
  Form,
  FormGroup,
  FormControl,
  Panel,
  Row,
  Col,
  Tabs,
  Tab,
  ListGroup,
  ListGroupItem,
  Glyphicon
} from 'react-bootstrap'

const friendsOnline = [
  {name: "Piotr Iksiński", messages: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.'},
  {name: "Jan Kowalski", messages: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.'}
]

const CloseableTab = ({title, onTabClose}) => {
  return (
    <div className="tab-title">
      {title}
      <Glyphicon glyph="remove" onClick={onTabClose}/>
    </div>
  )
}

class App extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      key: 1,
      activeConversations: []
    }
  }

  onFriendSelect(friend) {
    const {activeConversations, key} = this.state
    this.setState({
      key: key + 1,
      activeConversations: [
        ...activeConversations,
        friend
      ]
    })
  }

  onTabClose(e, conversation) {
    e.preventDefault()
    e.stopPropagation()
    const {activeConversations, key} = this.state
    this.setState({
      key: key - 1,
      activeConversations: activeConversations.filter(c => c.name !== conversation.name)
    })
  }

  onTabChange(key) {
    this.setState({
      ...this.state, // removing spread operator does not solve the inconsistency problem as key is still wrong - in other words old 
      key
    })
  }

  render() {
    const activeConversationsTabs = this.state.activeConversations.map((conversation, idx)=> {
      return (
        <Tab key={idx + 2} eventKey={idx + 2} title={
          <CloseableTab onTabClose={e => this.onTabClose(e, conversation)} title={conversation.name}/>
        }>
          <div>{conversation.messages}</div>
        </Tab>
      )
    })

    const friendsOnlineList = friendsOnline.map((friend, idx) => {
      return <ListGroupItem key={idx} onClick={() => this.onFriendSelect(friend)}>{friend.name}</ListGroupItem>
    })

    return (
      <div className="container">
        <Panel className="chat">
          <Row>
            <Col xs={8}>
              <Tabs id="chat" activeKey={this.state.key} onSelect={::this.onTabChange}>
                <Tab eventKey={1} title="Main">
                  <div>
                    Chat 1
                  </div>
                </Tab>
                {activeConversationsTabs}
              </Tabs>
            </Col>
            <Col xs={4}>
              <ListGroup>
                {friendsOnlineList}
              </ListGroup>
            </Col>
          </Row>
          <Row>
            <Col xs={12}>
              <Form inline>
                <FormGroup controlId="formInlineEmail">
                  <FormControl type="email" placeholder="jane.doe@example.com"/>
                </FormGroup>
                {' '}
                <Button bsStyle="success" type="submit">Join</Button>
              </Form>
            </Col>
          </Row>
        </Panel>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

App.propTypes = {}
App.defaultProps = {}

export default App
```

**Note the line** when I `preventDefault` and `stopPropagation`. That seems to solve the problem, but seems weird to me.

**Questions:**

1. Is my solution correct, and the way how it should be done?
2. Does my problem comes from wrong implementation?  What I mean by
   that everything is in a single component and I do not use any Flux
   or Redux. Using right tool for the job would solve the problem.